# How ARM cortex-M chip boot from 0x00000000?

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

My target is Atmel SAM4S series

Here is mapping table

[image: 1]

internal Flash start address is 0x00400000 and internal ROM start address is 0x00800000

As I know, ARM chip always boot from address 0x00000000, and I can select boot from internal ROM or from internal Flash by controlling boot register.

But how arm chip load ROM / Flash data into 0x00000000 by my selection?

Comment: Are you sure it does?

Comment: No, but I guess some hardware process must be done so ARM can boot from 0x00000000 with ROM/flash data by boot selection.

Comment: or they just made it boot from 0x00400000 or 0x00800000

Comment: Yes, of course, the fetches from address 0x00000000 are routed to the application flash based on how that chip configures this mirroring.   Likewise reads from the 0x00800000 space are routed to the application flash in a hardcoded way.  How else would it work?

Comment: It is as trivial in logic as it is in software to mirror these addresses, hardcoded or conditional/muxed.

Comment: Does it mean hardware will map 0x00400000/0x00800000  to 0x00  by my boot selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer from YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3brOzLJmeek&list=PLRJhV4hUhIymmp5CCeIFPyxbknsdcXCc8&index=16&t=3s

Seems hardware will map internal flash/ROM by boot select.